# Swiping between XML layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe, launcher, homescreen

I'm right now working on a launcher app and I have three `Activities`. User is on 2nd `Activity` by default and when user swipes left it should take him to 3rd `Activity` and when user swipes right it should take user to 1st `Activity`. Just like `Swipable Tabs` but the `Tabs` should not appear. Is it possible? Best example is of `Home Screen`, I want it exactly as `Home Screen`. I've tried a lot! But I'm not getting what ACTUALLY I want, any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use one activity including three fragments

Comment: But can I use whole `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as Fragments?

Comment: What you mean whole LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Comment: I mean can I swipe between `LinearLayouts` or `Relativelayouts`?

Comment: You can swipe between fragments, each fragment has its own layout as you want

Comment: Oh great! Can you show me an example? Please?

Comment: Follow the link provided by @Vishwajit Palankar

Comment: I'm a bit new to `Android` so it's little confusing, just show me a small example project, I will be very thankful! And I'll accept that answer!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can get you well.

First personally I don't suggest achieving this goal by using multiple activity. A better way might be one activity containing multiple fragment.

Then if you do so, several tools can make help, [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for example.

If you want to add some view page indicator, as what the homescreen looks like, then [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) might be a good choice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but can you show me an example how can I do this by using `Activities`? I'll accept your answer sure!

Comment: It will be different if you have to implement by using activities since viewpager does not support such activity switch as far as I know. A potential solution is to add a gesture listener to detect swipe and jump to the very activity accordingly. But i don't think it is a right way. Viewpager is a natural way to achieve your purpose unless you have reasons that you have to do it with multiple activities.

Comment: Yes you are right but what should I do further? Give up on this project? Well, this is not an option for me...